# Set index to group of repetitive row values in a csv file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, group-by

I am new to python. I want to set index to specific set of row elements which are repetitive for each group.
My dataframe:

[image: Index]

```
data_dict ={'0_deg': [2, 11, 21, -17, 5, 40, 22, 7, 20, -6, -6, -6, 24, 21, 20, 61, 21, 5, 2, 17], 
 '10_deg': [12, -21, 11, 1, 4, -2, 33, 53, 18, 10, -3, -1, 23, 18, 23, 8, 11, -25, 21, -14], 
 '20_deg': [23, -10, 3, 20, -41, 13, 10, 5, -9, 7, -4, -21, 14, -26, -31, 9, 1, -15, 3, -6], 
 '30_deg': [12, 9, -5, 4, 9, -46, 1, -8, -27, 3, -9, -14, 15, -6, 14, 7, -11, 5, 19, -4]}
```

```
data_dict = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')
data_dict = data_dict.set_index('Indexes')

#row idx of a group in this list
idx =[4,10,37,109,133]
```

Here a list is created as **idx** and index values are written maunally.

But for a bigger matrix of 1000+ indexes(random values) per group, this would be a very difficult task.

What I want is that when I read a CSV file, the 1st value in the row should be selected and until the same value occurs in the same index, it should be considered as 1 group, and the indexes for 1st group must get stored in **idx**

Eg: In my small version of dataset, from 1st column `Indexes`, the 1st values i.e. `4,10,37,109,133` are my indexxes for 1st group. These values repeat in same sequence for next groups. 
Only they shoud not be entered manually in code. A group should be considered unitl next `4` occurs. So index values 4 to 133 must be considered as 1 group under **idx**. This is because I need **idx** for further part of the code.

My actual dataset has 1000+ index values per group. So **idx** must automatically take all values of a group.

```
# getting some dimensions and sorting the data
row_idx_length = len(idx) 
group_length = len(data_dict['0_deg'])
number_of_groups = len(data_dict.keys())  
idx = idx*number_of_groups   
data_arr = np.zeros((group_length,number_of_groups),dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: Is possible last group have some values missing from repeating index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to actually get the idx given the dataframe with the index setup like that.

```
data_dict ={'0_deg': [2, 11, 21, -17, 5, 40, 22, 7, 20, -6, -6, -6, 24, 21, 20, 61, 21, 5, 2, 17], 
 '10_deg': [12, -21, 11, 1, 4, -2, 33, 53, 18, 10, -3, -1, 23, 18, 23, 8, 11, -25, 21, -14], 
 '20_deg': [23, -10, 3, 20, -41, 13, 10, 5, -9, 7, -4, -21, 14, -26, -31, 9, 1, -15, 3, -6], 
 '30_deg': [12, 9, -5, 4, 9, -46, 1, -8, -27, 3, -9, -14, 15, -6, 14, 7, -11, 5, 19, -4]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

idx =[4,10,37,109,133]
df.index = idx * (len(df)//len(idx))

print(df)
#Output:
     0_deg  10_deg  20_deg  30_deg  groups
4        2      12      23      12       1
10      11     -21     -10       9       1
37      21      11       3      -5       1
109    -17       1      20       4       1
133      5       4     -41       9       1
4       40      -2      13     -46       2
10      22      33      10       1       2
37       7      53       5      -8       2
109     20      18      -9     -27       2
133     -6      10       7       3       2
4       -6      -3      -4      -9       3
10      -6      -1     -21     -14       3
37      24      23      14      15       3
109     21      18     -26      -6       3
133     20      23     -31      14       3
4       61       8       9       7       4
10      21      11       1     -11       4
37       5     -25     -15       5       4
109      2      21       3      19       4
133     17     -14      -6      -4       4
```

With the setup done, you just need to calculate where the 0th value repeats. You could just calculate it directly, but perhaps it is also more useful to make an additional column for further calculations.

```
temp = df.index == df.index[0]
groups = temp.cumsum()
idx_out = list(df.index[groups == 1])

print(idx_out) #[4, 10, 37, 109, 133]

#Optional:

df['groups'] = groups #can be very useful for aggregations and groupby calculations
```

Comment: In your code you have created a list for index ```idx=[4,10,37,109,133]```. Is it possible,instead of entering all values , only the first value should be entered, E.g. **4** , so that **idx** will store values of 1st Column starting with **4** till next **4** occurs in that column?

Comment: can you elaborate "idx will store values of 1st Column starting with 4 till next 4 occurs in that column" ? I was under the impression you were already "getting" the indexes like that, and my initial `idx` was only part of the "setup". Are you not already getting an index with some kind of repetition?

Comment: If you just use the 2nd portion of the answer, assuming you're getting a dataframe with the index set like that, it will give you whatever the `idx_out` is for that dataframe.

Comment: I am getting the repetition at same intervals, but this is just case for 5 index values, my original data set has 5000 values, so **4** would repeat after 5000 odd values. So how to specify ```idx=[]``` for such case?

Comment: and the code here will work for 5000 values too, as long as your condition that the "first value does not repeat until the entire group repeats" is true. Try it out.

Comment: is your current question a good representation of what you need? Am i understanding you correctly or no? @AkshayK.

Comment: Yes.I am getting exact output as expected. Thankyou for the support.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with integer division for number of repeating:

```
df.index = np.tile(idx, len(df.index) // len(idx))
```

But if get error (`N` and `M` are some integer numbers):

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has N elements, new values have M elements

It means in last group missing some elements, so add next group by `1` and filter by length of `index of DataFrame`:

```
#added 150 to idx list
idx =[4,10,37,109,133,150]
df.index = np.tile(idx, len(df.index) // len(idx) + 1)[:len(df.index)]
print (df)          
     0_deg  10_deg  20_deg  30_deg
4        2      12      23      12
10      11     -21     -10       9
37      21      11       3      -5
109    -17       1      20       4
133      5       4     -41       9
150     40      -2      13     -46
4       22      33      10       1
10       7      53       5      -8
37      20      18      -9     -27
109     -6      10       7       3
133     -6      -3      -4      -9
150     -6      -1     -21     -14
4       24      23      14      15
10      21      18     -26      -6
37      20      23     -31      14
109     61       8       9       7
133     21      11       1     -11
150      5     -25     -15       5
4        2      21       3      19
10      17     -14      -6      -4
```

Comment: There are more than 1000+ elements per group. So how can I set them dynamically for **idx** ? I dont want to manually create a list like ```idx=[4,10,37,109,133,150]```

Comment: @anky_91 - hmmm, hard question, but if many element numpy should be faster.

Comment: @AkshayK. - How is count `idx` ?

Comment: In one of my dataframe, index starts with value ```4``` as shown. In another it may start with some other value. But whatever may be the value, it will repeat for each of the groups, also the range of indexes per group is fixed. E.g. from ```4``` to ```133`` the elements are fixed.

Comment: @AkshayK. - Not sure if understand, there are many another DataFrames for parse value for `idx`? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if possible in new question?

Comment: @AkshayK. - Or what is logic for starting number in another DataFrame?

Comment: Is it possible that idx should store the index value of one group dynamically. E.g.: If I take **1st index value** as input i.e. ```4```, then until next occurance of ```4``` occurs in ```Indexes```, my **idx** must store all the intermediate values as index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194150/discussion-between-jezrael-and-akshay-k).